# Druid only parse first json object of a json object list consumed from a single kafka message

Tags: apache-kafka, druid

A .NET/Java application generates a number of json objects (15.00-90.000) per second which includes various information about financial transactions. Those messages are send to a specific topic on Apache Kafka which will be consumed by the Druid (OLAP database).

Please find below the dataflow between the producer and consumer.

```
Produce    --               Persist/Distribute  --    Consume   
Application (.Net/Java) --> Apache Kafka Topic <--- Apache Druid (Kafka Indexing Service)
```

Message Payload (list of json objects)

```
{"filed1" : "value1" , "field2" : "value1"}
{"filed1" : "value2" , "field2" : "value2"}
...     
{"filed1" : "valueN" , "field2" : "valueN"}
```

The issue is that Druid only read (and ingest) only the first json object while ignoring the rest without prior error or warning.

> Note: If json objects are send one-by-one there is no issue however this not effective at all both network & application wise. In addition using `linger.ms` and `batch.size` kafka client properties is not an effective solution since number of generated messages is not known a priori.

Answer (score 1):

Finally after spending a lot of research hours I found that Druid(0.14) does not support out-of-the-box this functionality for the sake of the so-called `exactly-once` concept. However since verion 0.12 you will be able to write an extension module which will enable Druid to parse a single Kafka message into multiple individual Druid rows. An example can be found [here](https://github.com/implydata/druid-example-extension).